# I need to create a Display() Method, that will display all attributes

Tags: c++

I need to Add a display() method that displays all of the attributes. I'm not really sure how I can create a method that outputs all value types.
I tried doing void Display () but when I define it in the .cpp file It doesn't let me return or use any other value types. I need it to display or call all the attributes i.e. m_model, m_speed and m_engine_size.

```
#pragma once

class Car
{
private:
int m_speed;
int Maxspeed;
void turnOnBrakeLight(void);
public:
Car(void);
Car(int Speed);
Car(float engine_size, int speed);

char m_model[50];
float m_engine_size;
void accelerate(void);
void brake(void);
void Setspeed(int setspeed);
int getspeed();
void Setmaxspeed(int Setmaxspeed);
int Getmaxspeed();
};
```

/

```
# include "Car.h"
void Car::accelerate(void)
{
m_speed++;
}

void Car::brake(void)
{
m_speed--;
turnOnBrakeLight();
}

void Car::turnOnBrakeLight(void)
{
// turn on brake light
}
void Car::Setspeed(int setspeed)
{
m_speed = setspeed;
}

int Car::getspeed()
{
return m_speed;
}

void Car::Setmaxspeed(int Setmaxspeed)
{
Maxspeed = Setmaxspeed;
}
int Car::Getmaxspeed()
{
return Maxspeed;
}

Car::Car(void)
{
m_speed = 0;
m_engine_size = 0.0f;
m_model[0] = 'N';
m_model[1] = 'o';
m_model[2] = 'n';
m_model[3] = 'e';
m_model[4] = '\0';

}
Car::Car(int speed)
{
m_speed = speed;
m_engine_size = 0.0f;
m_model[0] = 'N';
m_model[1] = 'o';
m_model[2] = 'n';
m_model[3] = 'e';
m_model[4] = '\0';

}
Car::Car(float engine_size, int speed) 
{
m_speed = speed;
m_engine_size = engine_size;
m_model[0] = 'N';
m_model[1] = 'o';
m_model[2] = 'n';
m_model[3] = 'e';
m_model[4] = '\0';
}

Car::Display()
{


}
```

/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;

// DECLARE functions
void wait_for_keypress(void);

int main()
{
Car daves_car_1;
Car daves_car_2(55);
Car daves_car_3(2.5, 55);
cout << daves_car_1.m_model << ", " << daves_car_1.m_engine_size << ", " << daves_car_1.getspeed() << endl;
cout << daves_car_2.m_model << ", " << daves_car_2.m_engine_size << ", " << daves_car_2.getspeed() << endl;
cout << daves_car_3.m_model << ", " << daves_car_3.m_engine_size << ", " << daves_car_3.getspeed() << endl;
wait_for_keypress();
}

// DEFINE functions
void wait_for_keypress(void)
{
cout << "Press any key to continue" << endl;
_getch();
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to write a method that displays *one* attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `display` method as follows:

```
#include <string>

class Car {

private:
    int m_speed;
    int Maxspeed;
    //...
public:
    //...
    std::string display() const {
        return "m_speed = " + m_speed + "\nMaxspeed = " + Maxspeed;
    }

};
```

where I have defined it in-class here, but you should put the definition in the implementation file as usual. All this `display` method does is return a `std::string` with the relevant field variables associated with an instance of `Car`. You can then just do

```
Car _car;
std::cout << _car.display();
```

to display the `std::string` representation of the `Car` properties. You can extend this to include all your other fields as necessary, note however that `char m_model[50]` should be changed to `std::string m_model` to avoid needing to mess with pointer to `char` types - `std::string` provides a "managed" `char` container for easier string manipulation.

Also, as you have `std::cout << car_instance;` code snippets in your question - it is indeed possible to overload the `operator<<` for a user-defined type. In this case (for example):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& _os, const Car& _car) {
    _os << _car.display();
    return _os;
}
```

[Note stream insertion/extraction operators are free-functions so should be defined outside the class.]

This overloaded `operator<<` then allows you to use `std::cout` (or any other `ostream`) on instances of the class `Car`.